# How to write $\sin^2(z)$ in terms of imaginary units.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, trigonometry

I know:

$$\sin(z) = \Im e^{iz}$$

What about $\sin^2(z)$?

$$\sin^2(z) \ne \Im e^{2iz}$$

Advice?

Comment: @graydad different ways of writing the same expression. The easiest thing is just to say $\sin^2(z)=(\mathcal{I} e^{iz})^2$. To write something in terms of $e^{2iz}$ you need to use double angle formulas like those for $\cos 2z$.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Ah, thanks for clarifying. I had not seen that notation before.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that $\Im$ does not preserve multiplication - that is, $\Im(xy)$ is not necessarily equal to $\Im(x)\Im(y)$ - in particular $\Im(x^2)$ may differ from $\Im(x)^2$.

However, one can make this work - one can notice that $\Im(z)=\frac{z-\bar z}{2i}$ where $\bar z$ is the conjugate of $z$. You can prove this by setting $z=a+bi$, or just noting that $z-\bar z$ represent a line from $\bar z$ to $z$, which is parallel the imaginary line and twice the desired length.

In particular the conjugate of $e^{iz}$ is $e^{-iz}$, thus we can write:
$$\sin(z)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$
and squaring this gives
$$\sin(z)^2=\frac{e^{2ix}-2+e^{-2ix}}{-4}.$$
Notice that that can be rewritten as:
$$\sin(z)^2=\frac{1-\Re(e^{2ix})}{2}=\frac{1-\cos(2x)}2$$

Comment: You probably want an $x$ instead of a $z$.